# CSS div overflow issue

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a simple chat room using CSS which consist of their message and their username. What I have done is I've wrapped the message and username inside a `<div>`. The problem occurs when the message goes over the `<div>`. It doesn't push other `<div>`s containing other message below.

Thank you for helping me.

here the jsiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gjuv8/

[image]
[image]

**CSS**

```
 body { background-color: #535954}
 .box22 {  content: "";display: block;clear: both;background-color: #FFFFFF;width: 500px;height:400px;position: relative;left: 450px;top: 230px; }

 .user{font-size:18px;font-family:Arial;color: #3A3E42 ;font-weight: bold;float:right;position: relative;left: -20px;top: 0px;}
 .message{font-size:18px;font-family:Arial;color: #3A3E42 ;font-weight: bold;float:left;position: relative;left: 10px;top: 40px;}
 .wrapper{position: relative;left: 10px;top: 50px;background-color: #FFFFFF;width: 480px;height: 100px}
```

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/float.css">
<div class="box22">

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="user">johnny123 </span>
<span class="message">message  message overflow message  message overflowmessage  message overflowmessage  message overflowmessage  message overflow</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">d
<span class="user">glasses glasses </span>
<span class="message">michael </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 For a clearly framed question.

Comment: without looking too closely at your code, I think you can accomplish it by simply using `float: left` and `clear: left` in the wrapper class. To bring the contents of it a little bit to the right, you can use `padding-left: 10px`.

Comment: If you want to show whole messages why do you put height: 100px there? And you don't need to float the elements there I think. I think you are making something easy into something difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot to change to make it work

```
  body { background-color: #535954}
    .box22 {  content: "";display: block;clear: both;background-color: #FFFFFF;width: 500px;height:400px;position: relative;left: 450px;top: 230px; }

    .user{font-size:18px;font-family:Arial;color: #3A3E42 ;font-weight: bold;text-align:right}
    .message{font-size:18px;font-family:Arial;color: #3A3E42 ;font-weight: bold;}
    .wrapper{position:relative;background-color: #FFFFFF;width: 480px;}
```

Check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gjuv8/1/) here

Comment: @JackRoster: wellcome, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 3):

may i sure try this css :

```
body {
    background-color: #535954
}
.box22 {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    left: 450px;
    top: 230px;
}
.user {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #3A3E42;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    top: 0px;
}
.message {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #3A3E42;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 32px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 480px;
    height: 100px
    margin:5px 0;
}
```

html source :

```
<div class="box22">
  <div class="wrapper"> <span class="user">johnny123 </span> <span class="message">message  message overflow message  message overflowmessage  message overflowmessage  message overflowmessage  message overflow</span> </div>
  <div class="wrapper"> <span class="user">glasses glasses </span> <span class="message">michael </span> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work for u irrespectively to reduce ur code.For the messages and name u put one container div. just put float:left; min-height:"some required height" ; height:auto; for ur container div. it will simply lead u to go with expanded height

Answer (score 0):

You are just setting to much static heights and widths ... i would do it like the code below ... let me know if it works for your need, cheers

CSS :

```
 body {
        background-color: #535954
    }

    .box22 {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        position: relative;
    }

    .user {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #3A3E42;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 2%;
    }

    .message {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #3A3E42;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="box22">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="user">johnny123 </div>
        <div class="message">message
            message overflow message message overflowmessage message
            overflowmessage message overflowmessage message overflow
            <br />
            overflowmessage message overflowmessage message overflow
            <br />
            overflowmessage message overflowmessage message overflow
            <br />
            overflowmessage message overflowmessage message overflow
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="user">glasses glasses </div>
        <div class="message">
            michael
            <br />
            overflowmessage message overflowmessage message overflow
            <br />
            overflowmessage message overflowmessage message overflow
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i just tried ur solution , you need to specify a <br> otherwise  the content is just going to overflow outside the div , thank u for the help :)

Comment: Oh, no, i jus put the <br/>'s there to save lines of text, try to remove them and write big ammounts of text you will see the same effect ... cheers